# bijective function from a circle to a line

Tags: geometry

I am just reading a book which says the square has the same size as the line. It is saying every coordinate in the square have two coordinates x and y, and we can make a bijective function this in a line if we transform the coordinates as $ z = .x_1 y_1 x_2 y_2\dots $. Ex: $ x=1/2$ and $ y=1/3 $ $\to z= 0.530303030\dots$
Read this, I thought actually we could use this to map circle also (actually for any shape)  Every point on the circe line is map like this for just one point on the line. Also they cardinality stay same. Is this correct?

If yes what happens if one of the coordinates is negative? Lat says one of the point on the circle x=2 and y = -3,  So if how we organise these numbers after each other.  $ 0.2(-3)00 $ Obviously it is not looking right.

Comment: When you say "circle", do you mean just the edge of the circle, or the whole, filled-in disc? Not that it really matters for the final answer, but it may affect the details of any example people give you.

Comment: I mean the just the edge.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

No. That map is specifically constructed to work for points in the square $[0, 1]\times[0, 1]$. Any other shape (including a square at a different place in the plane, but also circles, or more exotic things) would require some alteration to the function description.

It is definitely possible, but it's not *as* pretty to describe exactly how the map works. You can't just interleave the digits and call it a day.

Besides, you have to be a bit careful with the whole $0.999\ldots = 1$ issue. For instance,
$$
z = 0.5303030\ldots
$$
corresponds to $x = \frac12, y = \frac13$, but so does
$$
z = 0.4393939\ldots
$$
so it's not really a bijection as stated.

Comment: Is there any name for "That map"? Actually, the book does not mention, so it is limiting me to read about more. I guess "That map" somehow handle the 0.999 = 1 problem, but in my text there is no mention it. So actually the map is working or not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there exists a bijective function between any circle and any interval of $\mathbb R$.

For example, for the basic circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and the interval $[0,1)$ you can construct bijective the mapping

$$t \mapsto (\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t))$$

For any other circle and any other half-open interval, you can first map the circle to the unit circle, and the interval to the unit interval, and use the same function.

Comment: I suspect that by "circle", the OP really means "disc". Not sure, though.

Comment: @Arthur Hmm. Possibly. In that case, of course, the answer is a little more complicated. Still a "yes", but more complicatedly so :)

Comment: I mean circe not disk.

Comment: thanks the answer.